# WCF Service WSDL definition with selective endpoints by implementing IWsdlExporteExtension

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I have a service with two endpoints:

```
<service name="WcfService4.Service1">
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="myBinding"
              contract="WcfService4.IService1"
              binding="basicHttpBinding">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint name="wsEndpoint"
              contract="WcfService4.IService1"
              binding="wsHttpBinding">
    </endpoint>
<service>
```

This service will be consumed by Framework 2.0 and 4.0 clients. When adding a web service reference from the 2.0 client all is well. When I add a service reference from the 4.0 client, both endpoints are created making the client specify which endpoint it would like to use.

What I’d like to achieve is to give the user the option of either downloading: basicHttpBinding endpoints or wsHttpBinding endpoints for the service but not both, so framework 4.0 clients will have by default only one endpoint.

By default the path to retrieve the wsdl definition would be:

```
http://[server]:8080/MyApp/service.svc?wsdl
```

Would It be possible to serve the wsdl definition on another url?:

For instance:

> http://[server]:8080/service.svc/basic?wsdl
>   http://[server]:8080/service.svc/ws?wsdl

By implementing a custom endpoint behavior with an IWsdlExportExtension implementation I could possibly hide endpoints from being exported based on the request.

I’d like to know if this is even possible, if my approach would be correct or if I am completely wrong and either this can’t be done of I’m complicating things a bit too much. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK on an WSDL export extension you don't get the request which originated the WSDL creation process. But you can do that, by using a non-SOAP (a.k.a. REST) endpoint to expose the WSDL. In this example it simply sends a HTTP request to the service itself to get the WSDL, then "trims" the resulting WSDL (XML) of the endpoints which were not requested.

After running this code, if you run

```
svcutil http://localhost:8000/service/conditionalwsdl/getwsdl?endpoint=basic
```

You'll only get the endpoint with `BasicHttpBinding`, while if you run

```
svcutil http://localhost:8000/service/conditionalwsdl/getwsdl?endpoint=ws
```

You'll only get the endpoint with `WSHttpBinding`.

```
public class StackOverflow_15434117
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Echo(string text);
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IConditionalMetadata
    {
        [WebGet]
        XmlElement GetWSDL(string endpoint);
    }
    public class Service : ITest, IConditionalMetadata
    {
        public string Echo(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }

        public XmlElement GetWSDL(string endpoint)
        {
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            string baseAddress = OperationContext.Current.Host.BaseAddresses[0].ToString();
            byte[] existingMetadata = c.DownloadData(baseAddress + "?wsdl");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(new MemoryStream(existingMetadata));
            XmlElement result = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsManager.AddNamespace("wsdl", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/");
            nsManager.AddNamespace("soap11", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/");
            nsManager.AddNamespace("soap12", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/");

            List<XmlNode> toRemove = new List<XmlNode>();

            // Remove all SOAP 1.1 endpoints which are not the requested one
            XmlNodeList toRemove11 = result.SelectNodes("//wsdl:service/wsdl:port/soap11:address", nsManager);
            XmlNodeList toRemove12 = result.SelectNodes("//wsdl:service/wsdl:port/soap12:address", nsManager);
            foreach (XmlNode node in toRemove11)
            {
                if (!node.Attributes["location"].Value.EndsWith(endpoint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    toRemove.Add(node);
                }
            }

            foreach (XmlNode node in toRemove12)
            {
                if (!node.Attributes["location"].Value.EndsWith(endpoint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    toRemove.Add(node);
                }
            }

            List<string> bindingsToRemove = new List<string>();
            foreach (XmlNode node in toRemove)
            {
                string binding;
                RemoveWsdlPort(node, out binding);
                bindingsToRemove.Add(binding);
            }

            toRemove.Clear();
            foreach (var binding in bindingsToRemove)
            {
                string[] parts = binding.Split(':');
                foreach (XmlNode node in result.SelectNodes("//wsdl:binding[@name='" + parts[1] + "']", nsManager))
                {
                    toRemove.Add(node);
                }
            }

            foreach (XmlNode bindingNode in toRemove)
            {
                bindingNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(bindingNode);
            }

            return result;
        }

        static void RemoveWsdlPort(XmlNode wsdlPortDescendant, out string binding)
        {
            while (wsdlPortDescendant.LocalName != "port" && wsdlPortDescendant.NamespaceURI != "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/")
            {
                wsdlPortDescendant = wsdlPortDescendant.ParentNode;
            }

            binding = wsdlPortDescendant.Attributes["binding"].Value;

            var removed = wsdlPortDescendant.ParentNode.RemoveChild(wsdlPortDescendant);
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new BasicHttpBinding(), "basic");
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WSHttpBinding(), "ws");
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IConditionalMetadata), new WebHttpBinding(), "conditionalWsdl")
            .Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress + "/basic"));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.Echo("Hello"));

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```